Wiring a new light fitting (pre 2004 wiring)
I am trying to wire a light fitting. I have 3 green (earth), 3 red (live) and 3 black (2 neutral and 1 switch live). I have identified the black cable that is the switch live. I have put the switch live into the live box, the other two black in the neutral and the three earth cables into the earth box. The 3 red cables I have safely put into a separate box not connected the light. However now the light will only remain on. When I use the switch nothing happens and the light remains on. Any ideas?

What are these "boxes" you mention? Are they wire connectors? Also, let's not confuse wires with cables. Wires are single conductors, which may comprise multiple strands. Cables are bundles of wires. Please revise to clarify.

By the black neutrals, I imagine you are in the UK/Europe.  One of the reds should go to the switch for power, and the switch live goes to fixture power wire.  The fixture neutral goes to the other neutrals.  A picture will be nice.

If this is the UK, you probably have 'ancient colours' (solid green not green/yellow).  Here's a wiring diagram for a typical ceiling rose:

(source, can highly recommend his videos too)
We are lacking in details, but when you say you identified the switched live, is that through red or brown sleeving, or something else?
Your description is unclear but it sounds like it matches the diagram.  Are you sure the switched live is actually being switched?  eg if the switch was wired wrong it's possible the switched live is always live.
